Update of Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 failed to download repository information
I want to update Linux Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 running on Oracle VM Virtual Box 7.0.20. Though I cannot do it in one step, I have to do it with 2, the first one should be an Update to version 20.04.
I tried it first with the software updater of the desktop. It shows me the following message:

Failed to download repository information. Check Your internet connection.

But on Firefox internet is working perfectly.
Now I tried it on the terminal with
sudo apt-get update

I get the following type of errormessages:
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20140517T222731Z jessie/updates InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8B48AD6246925553...
and
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used...
I've already been on many sites, but I cannot find any useful hint.
Could anybody help me..?
Thanks in advance

Sadly, you have stuck with Ubuntu 18.04 past it's End-Of-Life date (April, 2023), there's no longer an easy upgrade path. The difficult upgrade path is, well, difficult, and probably should not be attempted. Determine your configuration, what software you've installed, from where (and if that decision is correct now), backup /ete/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow}, backup user home directories, install to a supported release. See https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/ Your task would be made easier if /home were a seperate partition.

@waltinator They can upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu still there's ways to do so via oldreleases.  However, OP in this case is using Debian repositories too and that is broken.  Since they have a "mix and match" system at this point they're better off clean installing as the answer says though.

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/   After a release goes EOL, the not-receiving updates also means certificates when expired will not be renewed.  The link I provided says rather clearly "Regular security support updates have been discontinued as of June 17th, 2018." so I suggest you better maintain your software, as you've been ignoring that for some time...

Please remove the Debian repository, and also uninstall the software you installed from that repository.
To remove the Debian repository, open Software & Sources, go to other software, and disable this repo.

You may find it simpler to fresh install 24.04 instead of upgrading so many times.
